# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So this is probably a "rookie"-type query, but I am so stuck on how to resolve this error.  Basically I am wanting certain channels to automatically update stats within the server.
Running latest versions of Node.JS and Discord.JS.

```
[Error] An error happened in process: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/container/events/Stats.js:20:29)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

The file that relates to it is Stats.JS:

```js
function updateStats(client) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const config = require("../settings/configuration");
    const settings = require("../settings/configuration");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID);
    const totalUsers = require("../settings/configuration");
    const onlineUsers = require("../settings/configuration");
    setInterval(async function() {
    //const interval = (async function() {
 /*       for await (const startTime of setInterval(interval, Date.now())) {
          const now = Date.now();
          console.log(now);
          if ((now - startTime) > 1000)
            break;
        }
        console.log(Date.now());
      })();
      */
      console.log('Getting stats update..')
      var userCount = guild.members.size //guild.memberCount || 0;
      var onlineCount = guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
      console.log("Total Users: " + userCount);
      console.log("Online Users: " + onlineCount);
      totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      }, 120000 /* 30000*/) // update every 2 mins
      }

    module.exports = {
    updateStats
    }
```

As I suspect it will be needed, this is my Config file:

```js
module.exports = {
    BOT_SETTINGS: {
        BOT_TOKEN: 'token',
        YT_API_KEY: 'key',
        COMMAND_PREFIX: '?',
        EMBED_COLOR: 'BLUE',
        MUTE_ROLE: '901132102983102575',
        TIMEOUT_ROLE: '901132500229828638',
        BANNED_WORDS: ['**', '**'],
        BYPASS_ROLES: ['900730714457264218', '900730787392028692', '897570746660950026'],
        BANNED_LINKS: ['www.', '.com', '.net', '.gov', '.co', '.uk', '.gg', '.live'],
        BYPASS_LINKS_ROLES: ['900730714457264218', '900730787392028692', '897570746660950026'],
        Member_Count_Channel: '',
        Guild_ID: '896058387542974494',
        Kick_On_Warnings: true,
        Warnings_Until_Kick: '5',
        Time_Muted: '1m',
        LOCALE: 'en',
        Roles_On_Join: ['901133176506822696']
    },
    VERIFICATION: {
        Enabled: false,
        Verify_Channel: 'CHANNELID',
        Verify_Role: '900730843281125376',
        Role_To_Remove: '901133176506822696'
    },
    USER_DMS: {
        Enabled: true,
        Dm_Category: '',
        Dms: 'new-dm-{user}',
        Dm_Channel_Name: 'new-dm-{user}',
        View_Dmchannels_Roles: ['900730714457264218', '900730787392028692', '897570746660950026']
    },
    Ping_Prevention: {
        Enabled: true,
        Enabled_Types: 'user',
        Max_Channel_Pings: '5',
        Max_Role_Pings: '5',
        Max_User_Pings: '5',
        Max_Pings: '10',
        Punishment: 'kick',
        Bypass_Roles: ['900730714457264218', '900730787392028692', '897570746660950026']
    },
    LOCKDOWN_KICK: {
        Enabled: true,
        Kick_Message: '{server} is currently in LOCKDOWN MODE!  We are unable to allow you to join for now, please try joining back later {member}.'
    },
    LEVELING_SYSTEM: {
        Enabled: true,
        Remove_XP_On_Leave: true,
        Level_Up_Message: '{user} has just reached VC Level {level}!',
        Level_Up_Channel_ID: '901140182735134731'
    },
    LOGGING: {
        Report_Channel: '900749525646446622',
        Ban_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Unban_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Kick_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Warn_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Mute_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Lock_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Ticket_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Moderation_Channel_Logs: '900749525646446622',
        Server_Updates: '900749525646446622',
        Voice_Updates: '900749525646446622'
    },
    TICKET_SYSTEM: {
        TICKET_CATEGORY: '',
        SUPPORT_TEAM_ROLES: ['900730714457264218', '900730787392028692', '897570746660950026',]
    },
    GREETING_SYSTEM: {
        Enabled: true,
        Welcome_Channel: '896058387979190393',
        Welcome_Type: 'card',
        Welcome_Cards_Image_Link: 'https://ptb.discord.com/channels/835428942570586143/901135850610499695/901139883433795604',
        Welcome_Message: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
        Welcome_Embed: {
            title: '{member.username} has just joined the server!',
            description: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
            color: 'blue'
        }
    },
    stats: {
              "totalUsers": '902148987845488650',
              "onlineUsers": '902149028110811136',
              "onlineStaff": '902149128195284993'
            }
          }
```

Any help greatly appreciated...  this has been bugging me for months!

Comment: Try `client.guilds.fetch(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID)`

Comment: You star!  Thank you!

Comment: Now giving me this error:
```TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined```

Comment: When you have `xxx.yyy.zzz` in your code and encounter `Cannot read property 'zzz' of undefined` error, it means `xxx.yyy` is `undefined`. Try to use `console.log(xxx)` to check if the value of `xxx` is expected. In your case, you may want to add `console.log(guild)` to check if the `guild` variable is a valid Guild instance.

Answer (score 0):

The comments here are mostly correct.

Discord.js v12+ uses caching as opposed to `.get("id")` just working.

So yes, you'd need to use `client.guilds.fetch("id")` which returns a promise instead.

So instead, make your function asynchronous (unless you'd prefer to wrap everything in .then(), this is the simpler method)

```js
// Example, missing out a fair bit of your code, just showing the things you need to edit

async function updateStats(client) {
    let guild = await client.guilds.fetch(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID,{ force:true, cache:true }); // force skips cache checking, cache will cache the user    let members = await guild.members.fetch({ force:true, cache:true, withPresences:true }); // fetches *all* members of the guild, withPresences returns the user's presences, otherwise most will be nullish
    let onlineCount = members.filter(m => m.presence?.status === 'online').size;
}
```

I also recommend using [guild.memberCount](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) over `guild.members.size` or `members.size` using the fetched members, just so it's more accurate.

I know I'm pretty late to answering so you might've figured it out yourself, but if not hopefully this helps.